# How to put a production version of django site online?

Tags: python, django

I have been developing a django application. I am using digital ocean. So I have placed my website folder into the `../var/www/html/[app_name]` folder.

Normally, when I want to put my website online for users to use, I use:

```
cd ../var/www/html/[app_name]

python manage.py runserver [my_ip_address]:8080
```

But when I close my SSH. My website goes offline again.

I want to put it online directly on the ip address without any port like normal websites are. But I dont know how to do this in django as I have to run manage.py in order to put it online.

I know its a really simple problem but I dont seem to get my head around it. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I shall be very thankful.

Comment: Its not a really simple problem.  Search digital ocean for how to set up nginx and gunicorn to serve django.  There are a few configuration files to set up.  You also have to set up upstart or systemd or whatever bootstrap system is in use on your droplet so that if the machine reboots, your website also reboots.  Take a week before you get frustrated! lots of tinkering

Comment: This is my checklist: http://joelgoldstick.com/blog/2016/apr/03/notes-deployment-digital-ocean/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `python manage.py runserver [my_ip_address]:8080` in a production environment is not the best.

And the problem is not as trivial as you think. Digital ocean has a good tutorial on setting up a production environment:
[How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04).

You will also be looking to automate some of your processes (like your gateway server), using say [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html).

There is also a very good blog on setting up everything together: [Setting up Django with Nginx, Gunicorn, virtualenv, supervisor and PostgreSQL](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

In the end, you will have a checklist of items that will make your production server more robust and fail proof. Take your time. This is in your best interest in the long run.